# How to return database query into ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to check if a user has favourited an item but I'm unsure how to return the result of a database query to ajax.

I will show different html depending on the result.

Php

```
$query = "SELECT itemID from favourites WHERE userid = '" . $user. "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Jquery

```
$.ajax({
  url: "inc/functions.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {--result--},
  success: function () {

      // if result found in database 
         $('favourite').hide();

      // if result not found
         $('favourite').show();
      }
});
```

I can't figure out how to display $result in the jquery code.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: The content of the HTTP response is passed to the `success` handler function, so you would add an argument to that function in order to observe that response.  What that response is and how you use it is up to you, really.  I don't think `$result` is what you think it is in this case.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks for info, I updated to mysqli and got it working in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments for info regarding mysqli. I updated the code and solved the ajax part.

For anyone else stuck, I got it working like this:

PHP

```
require ("../../connection.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE userID = ? AND itemID = ?";
$user = $_POST['userID'];
$item = $_POST['itemID'];

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
if($statement === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $db->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$statement->bind_param('ii',$user,$item);

$statement->execute();

$statement->bind_result($user,$item);

while($statement->fetch()){
    echo 1;
}

$statement->close();
```

Jquery

```
$.ajax({
url: "inc/userList.php",
data: userList,
type: "POST",
success: function (result) {

   if (result == 1){
      $('#addItem').css('display', 'none');
      $('#removeItem').css('display', 'inline-block');
    } else {
      $('#addItem').css('display', 'inline-block');
      $('#removeItem').css('display', 'none');
    }    
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$result` in this case is a PHP object representing a result.
You will have to use a `fetch()` method in order to extract the result before sending it back to your JS.

See [this link](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-fetch-row.php). There's a list of all `fetch`-family method right above the comments.

Also, you will need to make a connection with you database beforehand using `mysqli_connect` (or `mysql_connect` in your case).

As stated in the comments, you should however use `mysqli*` functions family instead of `mysql*`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look into fetch() now.